# R: Store a variable's content to be returned by a function that is not changed if object is re-assigned

Tags: r, function, variables, environment-variables

I need to create a function to return a piece of data stored as a variable. However, this variable will get re-assigned later. How can I specify a function to return the *current content* of a variable (without assigning a unique variable to it), rather than the call to that variable when the function is executed?

```r
v <- mtcars[["mpg"]]

v
#>  [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4
#> [16] 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7
#> [31] 15.0 21.4

f <- function(x) v  # I would like to here specify "the content of v" and not v the variable

# Because otherwise, if v gets re-assigned...
v <- 3

# the function pulls the new variable (which is expected, but is not what I need)
f()
#> [1] 3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

I tried for instance: `f <- function(x) eval(v)` with the hope that it would be the "content" that is stored in the function, but it doesn't work.

### Partial Solution and Follow-up Issue

While @Waldi 's answer work in the example I gave, I forgot to add that, to make things worst, I actually need this function to be stored in a list (I don't make the rules haha), which breaks the suggested double-function solution, as the object in the list returns a function instead of the content of the variable:

```r
v <- mtcars$mpg
f <- function(x) function() x
thelist <- list("specific_name" =  f(v))

thelist[["specific_name"]]
#> function() x
#> <environment: 0x000000001419c068>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Note that calling the object in the list `thelist$specific_name()` or `thelist[["specific_name"]]()` works, but is not an option in my case (because the package that takes the list of functions as input does not call the functions but simply retrieves them "normally" [without `()`] and expects values).

Comment: I have to use a function from a package that uses a function as input instead of a vector of values. So I have to create a function that returns values. Because of how the code is made (in a loop), the variable where the values are stored will get re-assigned at each iteration, hence the need of storing the variable's content rather than its call. Naturally I could generate a new list with a unique identifier and store there the content at each loop, but that doesn't seem like the most efficient solution (that would not require to create/store new objects)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function which returns a function where the current value is stored:

```r
v <- mtcars$mpg
f <- function(x) function() x
g <- f(v)
g()
#>  [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4
#> [16] 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7
#> [31] 15.0 21.4
v <- 3
g()
#>  [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4
#> [16] 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7
#> [31] 15.0 21.4
```

Comment: Great thanks! Unfortunately, I have an additional constraint that doesn't seem to work with that solution (see post edit)... any work-aroud?

Comment: try : `thelist$f()`

Comment: That would work, but unfortunately I cannot call it (the name of the object has to match a particular pattern, which makes its call-ability not an option - it must be a regular name, `thelist[["somename"]]` has to return the values by itself)  :'(

Comment: `thelist$f` is a function as requested by your workflow. I don't understand why a package needing a function as input woudn't accept `thelist$f` which is also a function as shown in your edit. `h <- function(f) f(); g <- f(v); h(g)`

Comment: As illustration to "the package does not call the functions but simply retrieves them "normally" [without ()] ", try to call `mean` without `()`in console : you get a pointer to a function, as with `thelist$f`

Answer (score 0):

This is a kind of general solution...

```r
c_names <- c("am", "mpg")

fix_values <- function(value) {force(value); function() {value}}

out <- lapply(c_names, function(cn) {
  fix_values(mtcars[[cn]])
})

out[[1]]()
#>  [1] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

mtcars$am <- -99

out[[1]]()
#>  [1] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>